# Chance in groups

Tags: probability

If person A and B have a 20% chance to be in group 1, a 40% chance to be in group 2 and a 40% chance to be in group 3, what is the chance for person A and B to be in the same group?

I’ve tried picking random Numbers, 1/5 chance to get a one, 2/5 for a 2 or a 3, and i think that 36% is very reasonable as a correct answer

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E_{j,A}$ denote the event that $A$ is in the $j$th group $(1 \le j \le 3)$  and similarly define events $E_{j,B}$ for $B$ .

Then, $P(E_{1,A})= \frac{20}{100}=P(E_{1,B})$,$P(E_{2,A})= \frac{40}{100}=P(E_{2,B})$,$P(E_{3,A})= \frac{40}{100}=P(E_{3,B})$

Then your desired probability (say) $\mathscr{P}$= $\cup_{j=1}^3 P(E_{j,A} \cap E_{j,B})$ , since $E_{j,A}$ and $E_{j,B}$ are independent for fixed $j$ and for $i \ne j$ , $E_{j,A} \cap E_{j,B}$ is disjoint from $E_{i,A} \cap E_{i,B}$ we get that  $$\mathscr{P}= \sum_{j=1}^3P(E_{j,A}) P( E_{j,B})=(\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{100})+(\frac{40}{100} \times \frac{40}{100})+(\frac{40}{100} \times \frac{40}{100})= 0.36 $$

Answer (score 1):

36% I think...
$(0.2\times 0.2)+(0.4 \times 0.4) +(0.4 \times 0.4)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.